# android.jar (in Eclipse) update after making modification to Android framework?

Tags: eclipse, android-framework

I modified Android framework, and added my own service into. Now I want to use new methods and service.

However, when I opened Eclipse to do application-level app development that calls my new methods and service, Eclipse cannot resolve them.

What should I do at this moment? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile it with these commands (in bash):

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make sdk
```

This process may take a little more than an hour.
If you need the Windows SDK use:

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make win_sdk
```

Now you will have to point Eclipse to the new SDK located at:

```
out/host/platform/sdk/android-sdk_eng.username_platform-x86/
```

Or something similiar.

Comment: Thank you. That will be great if you can tell me how to point Eclipse to my new SDK. By the way, my understanding is SDK has nothing to do with framework; in other words, I should use lunch full_crespo-eng then make, instead of only making SDK. Am I correct?

Comment: I won't have access to Eclipse in the next few days, so I can't tell you exactly how to do that right now (but it's pretty straight forward). As for the SDK vs frameworks part, you are right, they use the same piece of code but they ate compiled differently. If you want the SDK (for use in Eclipse) then you must follow the instructions above. what you suggested would simply result in a compiled android image which you can use on your own device

Comment: True. Let me put it clearer. Correct me if wrong. Everything starts from my modification to, say, LocationManager.java in framework. *make sdk* you were saying is to compile all sources, and feed all generated class files to Eclipse. *make full_crespo-eng* I was saying is to compile all sources, and finally get a new system image. These two commands are used separately and independently. Am I correct? Thank you

Comment: Hello~ almost all sdk tools like adb fastboot dexdump.... were generated along with system.img. Then I deleted originally downloaded sdk folder and changes $PATH to new generated tools. You may know what happened: Eclipse cannot find original sdk any more and it also cannot locate my new tools. I wonder if I used your command (make sdk), shall I finally get a specific sdk folder that Eclipse can locate to? Thank you